# How to find vector orthogonal to a given pair of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

(a) $[2,-3,5], [4,-5,1]$

Solution:

$[2,-3,5]  \times [4,-5,1] = [22,18,2]$

No idea how they got $
[22,18,2]$

Comment: Just the cross product of those two vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross product of two vectors is a vector which is orthogonal to both vectors. In $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v}$, $\mathbf{w}$ is orthogonal to both $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

And to calculate cross product you may use the formula. For vectors $\mathbf{u}=[u_1, u_2, u_3 ]$ and $\mathbf{v}=[v_1, v_2, v_3]$:
$$ \mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v} = \begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{vmatrix} $$

and then expand the determinant from Row 1 ($i$, $j$ and $k$ are unit vectors).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the vector is $(x, y, z)$. Orthogonality means
\begin{align*}
2x - 3y + 5z = 0 \\
4x - 5y + z = 0
\end{align*}
Now fix $x$ (or $y$ or $z$) and solve for $y$ and $z$ in terms of $x$. This gives $22 y = 18 x$ and $22z = 2x$. Taking any nonzero $x$ yields the solution. Of course, $x=22$ would result in integer entries.